# RubyMineでRspecが動かない

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

RubyMine7.1.4
ruby-2.2.3-p173 SDK

の環境で開発をしています。

test_spec.rb(仮）にテストケースを書いて、RubMineでテストをしようとしましたが
下記のエラーでRspecの起動に失敗してしまいます

Error running Test: test: Cannot find RSpec runner script for ruby-2.2.3-p173 SDK

PreferenceのRuby SDK and Gems
でruby-2.2.3-p173が選択されていることと

試しにプロジェクト下で
gem install rspecをしたので
gemsの一覧には
rspec(3.3.0)と表示されていました。（エラーは修正できませんでした）

RubyMine上でGemfileを作成し、Bundle installした後も同じエラーがでます。

ターミナルから直接rspecを起動すると成功します

どういったRubyMineの設定で
RspecがRubyMineから起動できるかご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の手順で実行オプションを確認してください。
（以下の例はRailsを使わない素のRubyプロジェクトです）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Use project SDKになっているか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

bundle execで実行するようになっているか？
（逆にチェックを外すと動く場合もある）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それでもダメならhataさんの設定ウインドウを追記してください。

Comment: bundle execで実行するようになっているか？

このチェックで解決しました。
画像つきでご教授頂きありがとうございました。
実は伊藤さんのビンゴカード作成問題をやろうとしてrspecと格闘していました。RubyMineを使い始めたのも伊藤さんの影響です。
本当にありがとうございました

Comment: いえいえ、うまくいって良かったです！